# PHP documentation for extract's call result

Tags: php, extract

I have couple of variables which must be extracted by calling extract function. How can I to write phpdoc to tell my IDE (PHPStorm) which variables were extracted?

Answer (score 3):

There's an [**open issue**](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2416) at PHPStorm's tracker related to that. As for now, the suggested [workaround](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11207#comment=27-328962) is writing doccomments explicitly:

```
<?php
extract(array('asd' => 'val'));
/** @var $asd string */
do_something_with($asd);
```

... as obviously, you'd have to know the keys of the array processed by `extract` - as you'll use the variables named after them.

Then again, I do agree with the presenter of that issue: `extract` can save you some keypresses when you write the first version of your code, but there's a big chance it won't be worth a slice of the efforts wasted on fixing the subtle bugs introduced by it. In fact, some coding conventions strongly discourage using `extract` at all.